# get all rows matching a string in ay column using google app script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

i have a large spreadsheet, and a set of forbidden words, and i would like to remove all rows containing any of the words in any column. I have implemented a for loop in the words and i would like to get, for each word, all matching rows. For now, i'm using [2D ArrayLib](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library) and `IndexOf` function, that gives me the first row in which the word is present in any column. My problem is that the script exceed execution time, so i'm trying to optimize it as much as possible.

I'm posting a test example with my script so far, skipping the part in with i get the spreadsheet data into an `array` and then writing the filtered array it into a spreadsheet.

If you look at the code below,  the while loop deletes all rows one by one matching one word. **It is enough for me if i could replace the while loop**... i can deal with exceeding execution time afterwards.

```
function test(){
  var filters = []; 
  filter[0]='bye'
  filter[1]='hello';
  filter[3]='DOg';
  var array = [];
  array[0]=['hello todayis friday','and is cold'];
  array[1]=['not tomorrow','neverland'];
  array[2]=['anuthing','and bye'];
  array[3]=['what asdas','bye dog'];
  array[4]=['jejejje','the dog died'];
  array[5]=['lastone','bye'];
  var fil_array = array;   
  Logger.log(fil_array);  
  for (var i=0;i<filtro.length;i++){        
    var ind = ArrayLib.indexOf(fil_array, -1, filter[i]);
    while (ind>=0){      
      Logger.log(ind);
      fil_array.splice(ind,1);
      var ind = ArrayLib.indexOf(fil_array, -1, filter[i]);         
    }  
  }
  Logger.log(fil_array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the indices of the rows to remove.

```
function eliminateUnwantedWords()
{
  var uA=['bye','hello','DOg'];
  var sA=[['hello today is friday','and is cold'],['not tomorrow','neverland'],['anuthing','and bye'],['what asdas','bye dog'],['jejejje','the dog died'],['lastone','bye']];
  var rA=[];
  
  for (var i=0;i<sA.length;i++)
  {        
    var row=sA[i];
    for(var j=0;j<row.length;j++)
    {
        var wA=row[j].split(/\s+/);
        for(var k=0;k<wA.length;k++)
        {
          if(uA.indexOf(wA[k])>-1)
          {
            rA.push(i);
            break;
          }
        }
    }
      
  }
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(rA.join(','));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Indices of Rows to remove.')
}
```

This was my output:

[image]

If you are going to delete rows from a spreadsheet, I'd recommend start from the bottom and work your way back up.

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer. I'm might be missing something, but i don't see how this improve my code. I have 2 loops, while you have three. Remember that the problem is not that it doesn't work, but that execution time is too long for my real case spreadsheet.

Comment: It could be faster as I didn't use an external library and I didn't actually delete the rows.  But I didn't test it on your data so I don't really know.